# C++ low-level file encryption function

Tags: c++, encryption, directx

Please forgive my idiocy...I'm a PHP guy tasked with a C++ problem.

Our C++ application reads data from certain files. We would now like these files to be encrypted on the hard drive. I'm sure that just a C++ encryption library would be easy to find, but the application also calls some DirectX functions which also read the same files.

My team leader suggested the possibility of overriding a low-level file-reading function that is called by both our code as well as the DirectX functions.

My question is, is there some library out there that does this kind of thing already? Or, are we approaching this problem in a weird way at all?

Comment: Don't those DirectX functions provide a different way to access the data? Only taking input from files sounds like a poor design...

Comment: What functions are we talking about here?

Comment: Sorry, I know I'm not being very helpful, but I don't know the exact functions. I know they have to do with loading texture files.

Comment: Are you sure those files need to be encrypted? Can you solve the problem by setting the ACLs on those files appropriately so only a restricted account has access to them and then running your program in the context of that account?

Comment: You could also use file system encryption (Properties|General|Advanced...|Encrypt contents to secure data) and then use ACLs to restrict access to your program.

Comment: @Ferruccio: I think I like the sound of your second suggestion. I will have to do more research on that. Thanks. If you want to re-post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encrypt your files via the NFTS built-in encryption.
Then assign ACLs to those files which limit access to a restricted account and run your program in the context of that account or have the program perform a LoginUser() using the credentials of the restricted account before trying to read those files.

Comment: So this would require an additional user account to be set up, which is restricted so that the end-user is not able to log into it? Sorry for my misunderstanding...how feasible is it for the program (or installer) to set up a restricted account? Sorry, from your answer, I was under the impression that I could restrict access to just my program process, and not to a separate user account.

Comment: I don't know the details offhand, but your program can create accounts (as long as the account it's running under has the right privileges). An installer can also create accounts (that might actually be simpler than having the program itself create the account).

Comment: Hmm...I will definitely have to look more into this. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Well, [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/). Here's [binary distributions](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html). It's actually C, not C++, but i think it doesn't matter much.

See also [Crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com/).